# How to add a timestamp and error messages to Python rotating log?

Tags: python, logging

I created a rotating log for a Python project but can't seem to add timestamps for the debug log messages or any errors messages:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

path="Logs\Process.log"
handler = RotatingFileHandler(path, maxBytes=2000000,backupCount=5)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

This is how I am adding messages to the log. Only the text I put in quotes appears in the log but I'd want a timestamp for these messages and if the code errors out I would want that message as well:

```
logger.debug("Debug log message")
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s'))
```

after your `handler = ...` line. That puts a timestamp in the log.

Also I'd advise using a logger name related to a specific area of your application (such as a module) rather than a description like "Rotating Log". You can do this using `logging.getLogger(__name__)`.